# Placing a node label in a specific location

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-angles

I need the `\alpha_1` to be a bit close to the corner, it should be placed "nicely".

I tried the following code (with various numbers in label distance/angle):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove the page numbering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
%node[label={[label distance=0.05cm]90:$i_a$}]
\draw[->] (orig) -- (90:1) node[above] (ia) {$i_a$};
\draw[->] (orig) -- (10:1) node[right] (ib) {$i_b$};
\draw[->] (orig) -- (-45:1) node[right] (ic) {$i_c$};

\draw[blue] (10:0.2) arc (10:90:0.2) node[label={[label distance=-0.01cm]3:$\alpha_1$}] (asd) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

while yields the less attractive result:
[image]

But I want something like:
[image]

For some reason the code seems to behave in a manner that it's dodging from that corner... Many numbers which I tried simply avoided anywhere near that corner.

Comment: how about `inner sep=0`?

Comment: @Symbol1 Do you mean `node[inner sep=0, ` ?? It doesn't seem to improve much..

Comment: Have you considered using the `angles` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `angles` and `quotes` libraries together make this much easier.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
  \draw[->] (orig) -- (90:1) node[above] (ia) {$i_a$};
  \draw[->] (orig) -- (10:1) node[right] (ib) {$i_b$};
  \draw[->] (orig) -- (-45:1) node[right] (ic) {$i_c$};
  \pic [draw, blue, angle radius=2mm, "$\alpha_1$", angle eccentricity=2] {angle=ib--orig--ia};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: marking an angle]

Comment: Thanks! I tried using `angles` before submitting the current question - but it was giving me an error. Now - everything works fine. It seems that the code `\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}` is necessary - why? (Still I'd rather be familiar with additional method that allows adjusting the position manually)

Comment: @Dor You can use a different class as long as you load `tikz` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to put the text inside node and move the node itself using `postioning` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove the page numbering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
%node[label={[label distance=0.05cm]90:$i_a$}]
\draw[->] (orig) -- (90:1) node[above] (ia) {$i_a$};
\draw[->] (orig) -- (10:1) node[right] (ib) {$i_b$};
\draw[->] (orig) -- (-45:1) node[right] (ic) {$i_c$};

\draw[blue] (10:0.2) node[above right=0.1ex and -1ex] 
(asd) {\color{blue}$\alpha_1$} arc (10:90:0.2) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `positioning` library for that because you are using the deprecated syntax.

Comment: :))  TikZ changes so fast...

Comment: Indeed. It does. Are you going to update?

Comment: Which syntax is now used?

Comment: Thanks - where do I read about its syntax? (since that `positioning` is deprecated)

Comment: @Dor `positioning` is recommended. The syntax used by this library is e.g. `below left=of name` or `below left=2pt and 3pt of name` or `below left=5pt of name` or whatever.

Comment: @cfr I looked into the manual, and the syntax I used is still recommended for 2d motion