# Shift Arc Location --> Reference Angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I'm making worksheets to help students remember the unit circle and/or special triangles.

I want the blue arrow to represent the reference angle, between the terminal arm and the x-axis.

How do I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
 \newcommand{\MyScale}{1.75}

\newcommand{\OneFifty}
{%
Sketch \(\theta=150^\circ\) in standard position, labeling all sides, the angle, and the reference angle. Then, state all its trigonometric ratios.

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\MyScale]
\draw[thick,<->] (-2,0)--(1,0); % x-axis
\draw[thick,<->] (0,-1)--(0,1.5); % y-axis
\draw (0,0)--(-1.732,1); % terminal arm
\draw (-1.732,1)--(-1.732,0); % vertical drop
\draw (-1.532,0)--(-1.532,0.2)--(-1.732,0.2); %right-angle mark
\node[anchor=center] at (-0.866,-0.2) {A \(=-\sqrt{3}\)};
\node[anchor=center] at (-2.1,0.5) {OP \(=1\)};
\node[anchor=center] at (-0.8, 0.8) {H \(=2\)};
%Angle in standard position.
\node[red, anchor=center] at (1.4,0.3) {\(\theta=150^\circ\)};
\draw[red,->] (0.866,0) arc (0:150:0.866); % Angle in SP
\node[blue, anchor=center] at (-0.3,0.2) {\(\theta_{r} =30^{\circ}\)}; % Reference Angle label
\draw[blue,<->] (0.35,0) arc (150:180:0.35); % Reference Angle
\end{tikzpicture}%

\(\sin{150^\circ}=\frac{1}{2}\)

\(\cos{150^\circ}=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\)

\(\tan{150^\circ}=\frac{1}{-\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\)

\(\csc{150^\circ}=\frac{2}{1}=2\)

\(\sec{150^\circ}=\frac{2}{-\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\)

\(\cot{150^\circ}=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{1}=-\sqrt{3}\)
}

\begin{document}

\OneFifty

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\draw[blue,<->] (-0.35,0) arc (180:150:0.35); % Reference Angle`

Comment: Also have a look at the `angles` library, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359043/placing-a-node-label-in-a-specific-location/359047#359047

Comment: Thanks! This seems towork. Where is the center of the arc implied in `\draw[blue,<->] (-0.35,0) arc (180:150:0.35);`?

Comment: The center will be (0,0) of course. Think of it this way: when you do `arc(180:150:0.35)`, you can see this as placing a circle at the current point (`(-0.35,0)`), with the starting angle of the arc (`180`) as the "anchor", i.e. the point that is at 180 degrees of the circle is placed at (-0.35,0). And then only the part of the circle that is between the start angle and the end angle (`150`) is drawn.

Comment: Given the starting point of (-0.35,0) and a center at (0,0), then why is the `0.35` necessary in `(180:150:0.35)`?  And wouldn't `180` also already be implied?

Comment: Of course not. TikZ doesn't assume that you always want a arc/circle centered on `(0,0)` (why would it?), so you need to define start angle, end angle and radius, to fully specify the type of arc you want to draw.

Comment: Perhaps my comments have been a bit confusing. The center will be in (0,0) because of three things: 1) the starting point is (-0.35,0).  2) the starting *angle* is set to 180 degrees. 3) the radius of the circle is set to 0.35. If you did `\draw (-3.35,4) arc (180:150:0.35);` the center of the circle would be at (-3,4).

Answer (score 2):

This can be implemented elegantly using the `angles` library as suggested by @TorbjørnT. You need also `quotes` library to label angles. I changed all `\( .. \)` to `$ .. $`; there is nothing wrong with parentheses but it hurts my eyes and I prefer the more distinct symbol `$`. Finally, I don't think a `\newcommand` is very beneficial here as this figure is not likely repeated many times. You may think of removing the `newcommand` and inserting the figure as well as the text directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}   % <<----
\newcommand{\MyScale}{1.75}
\newcommand{\OneFifty}
{%
Sketch $\theta=150^\circ$ in standard position, labeling all sides, the angle, and the reference angle. Then, state all its trigonometric ratios.

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\MyScale]
\draw[thick,<->] (-2,0)coordinate(B)--(1,0)coordinate(C); % x-axis <<----
\draw[thick,<->] (0,-1)--(0,1.5); % y-axis
\draw (0,0)coordinate(O)--(-1.732,1)coordinate(A); % terminal arm  <<----
\draw (-1.732,1)--(-1.732,0); % vertical drop
\draw (-1.532,0)--(-1.532,0.2)--(-1.732,0.2); %right-angle mark
\node[anchor=center] at (-0.866,-0.2) {A \(=-\sqrt{3}\)};
\node[anchor=center] at (-2.1,0.5) {OP \(=1\)};
\node[anchor=center] at (-0.8, 0.8) {H \(=2\)};
% Angle in standard position.

\pic [draw,<->, blue, angle radius=8mm, "$\theta_{r} =30^\circ$", angle eccentricity=2] {angle=A--O--B};
\pic [draw,<->, red, angle radius=8mm, "$\theta=150^\circ$", angle eccentricity=1.4] {angle=C--O--A};

\end{tikzpicture}%

$\sin{150^\circ}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\cos{150^\circ}=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\tan{150^\circ}=\frac{1}{-\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

$\csc{150^\circ}=\frac{2}{1}=2$

$\sec{150^\circ}=\frac{2}{-\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$

$\cot{150^\circ}=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{1}=-\sqrt{3}$
}

\begin{document}

\OneFifty

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks promising in case I need to do many more diagrams. Do all of the `tikz` libraries have documentation to go with them?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything - Yes, check [the PGF manual](http://ctan.asis.io/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), it is a comprehensive guide with lots of examples from which you can learn and search for any piece of information you need.

Answer (score 2):

The @AboAmmar's answer seems me very good and satisfies the requirements of the question, although looking at your code I can see that there are many *coordinates* calculated *by hand* when **Tikz** provides powerful tools to calculate coordinates and node positioning. For example in `\draw (0,0)--(-1.732,1); % terminal arm` where `-1.732` is suposed equal to `-\sqrt{3}`, in this case can be more suitable to express this coordinate in polar form as `(150:2)` i.e an angle of `150` degrees and radius `2`.

Other common practice is to name the coordinates for later reference in calculations. Also to use positioning of labels of an a little more *automatic* way.

Due to the above considerations i decided rewrite the code using *my "own style"* so to say (not so much for solving the question, but for having fun for a while) leaving to **Tikz** to realize the bulk of the calculations.

Here a summary of my ideas:

- Naming a few coordinates in first instance, in fact only the ends of the axes, `(W)` `(E)` `(S)` `(N)` and the origin `(O)`.
- Automatic positioning of labels inside each path. For example

  ```
  \draw (p) -- node[left] {OP${}=1$} (p|-E) coordinate (pE); % vertical drop with its node 'OP=1'
  ```

  `(p|-E)` is calculated as a projection of `(p)` over `x-`axis and named `(pE)`.
- Using of the `angle` library to mark and label the angles such as in @AboAmmar's answer.
- I define a `pic` (inspired in the `pic {angle}`) to mark the *right angle*,

  ```
  \pic at (pE) {right angle}; % right-angle mark
  ```

  this wasn't really necessary but i'm learning to use the `pics` and i like that can be enriched with options and parameters, for example use

  ```
  \pic [fill,orange,transform shape] at (pE) {right angle}; % right-angle mark
  ```

  to `fill` with a color and `transform shape` makes the **pic** *scalable* with the `scale=<factor>` of the picture. If you want a mark with a different size you can use `right angle=<dimension>`, etc, for example

  ```
  \pic at (pE) {right angle=6mm}; % right-angle mark
  ```
- Finally i like the equal signs aligned thus i used the `alignedat` environment of the package [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) and the macro `\ang{...}` defined in the package [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) which parses numbers and measure units automatically.

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % For 'alignedat' environment
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}

\tikzset{% Define a ´pic´ to mark a right angle (square)
    pics/right angle/.style={%
        background code = {
            \path [pic actions] (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) -- ++(0,#1) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
        },
        foreground code = {
            \draw [pic actions] (0,0) ++(#1,0) -- ++(0,#1) -- ++(-#1,0);
        },
    },
    pics/right angle/.default=2mm
}

\usepackage{siunitx} 
\newcommand{\MyScale}{1.75}

\begin{document}
Sketch $\theta=\ang{150}$ in standard position, labeling all sides, the angle, and the reference angle. Then, state all its trigonometric ratios.

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\MyScale]
\coordinate (W) at (-2,0);  % West tip of 'x'
\coordinate (E) at (1,0);   % East tip of 'x'  
\coordinate (N) at (0,1.5); % North tip of 'y'
\coordinate (S) at (0,-1);  % South tip of 'y'
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);   % Origin
\begin{scope}[thick,<->]
\draw (W) -- (E); % x-axis
\draw (S) -- (N); % y-axis
\end{scope}
\draw (O) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.6] {H${}=2$} (150:2) coordinate (p); % terminal arm with its node 'H=2'

\draw (p) -- node[left] {OP${}=1$} (p|-E) coordinate (pE); % vertical drop with its node 'OP=1'

\pic [orange,transform shape] at (pE) {right angle}; % right-angle mark (scaled by \MyScale)

\path (O) -- node[below]  {A${}=-\sqrt{3}$} (pE); % node 'A=...' (adjacent)

%%Angles
\begin{scope}[angle radius=8mm, pic text options={font=\footnotesize}]
\pic [angle radius=13mm,draw,->, red, "$\theta=\ang{150}$", angle eccentricity=1.2] {angle=E--O--p}; % Angle in SP with its label
\pic [draw,<-, blue, anchor=east, "$\theta_{r}=\ang{30}$", angle eccentricity=1] {angle=p--O--W}; % Reference Angle with its label
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%

$\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\sin\ang{150}& &=\tfrac{1}{2}\\
&\cos\ang{150}& &=\tfrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}=-\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
&\tan\ang{150}& &=\tfrac{1}{-\sqrt{3}}=-\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
&\csc\ang{150}& &=\tfrac{2}{1}=2\\
&\sec\ang{150}& &=\tfrac{2}{-\sqrt{3}}=-\tfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
&\cot\ang{150}& &=\tfrac{-\sqrt{3}}{1}=-\sqrt{3}
\end{alignedat}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is a lot to absorb. I will take a closer look soon and get back to you. Thanks for doing all this work!